# Array List Loop Out of Bounds

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, compareto

I've got this code which I am developing below. I want to loop through two array lists, the first list I want to look at every entry, the second I only want to look at every 3rd entry and see if they match. If they do match then I want to compare the other two entries on the 2nd list. The problem with the code lies in the "int result1 = " line, I can't understand why it would say out of bounds. Any help much appreciated!

```
for (int i = 0; i < array1.size(); i++){
    for (int j = 3; j <array2.size(); j = j + 3) {
        if ((array1.get(i)).equals(array2.get(j-3))){
            int result1 = array2.get(j-1).compareTo(array2.get(j-2));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wrong error report. The code you report will never trigger index out of bounds. Have you shared everything?

Comment: Yes it def is, this is the error and it comes back on the line int result1....
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:

Comment: if I comment out the int result line, it works fine, no errors

Comment: The error can be cause you make magic operation with j-index

Comment: I need to use the j though because that's the index of array2. Unless I'm missing something! Which is likely!! ;-)

Comment: @RohitJain yeah rohit, just realized it :)

Comment: @Caz. You are really missing something. You are missing to post your real code here. Because the code shown will not throw the exception that you are saying.

Comment: @Caz post a test case inputs for your arrays with the stack trace

Comment: What is stored in the arrays? Add the stacktrace to your question.

Comment: maybe you are starting at the wrong index? what about starting `j = 2`
it seems as you are doing steps for 3 values, but you start with value 4

Answer (score 1):

This is an extended comment, not an answer.

It is clear that the posted code cannot produce the stated exception. There is something else going on. You need to prepare a [Simple, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org) that produces the exception. Here is an example of a program based on the code you posted that does not reproduce the problem. You need to post something similar, but with enough of your actual code to get the exception.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> array1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> array2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      array1.add(0);
      array2.add(0);
    }
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.size(); i++) {
      for (int j = 3; j < array2.size(); j = j + 3) {
        if ((array1.get(i)).equals(array2.get(j - 3))) {
          int result1 = array2.get(j - 1).compareTo(array2.get(j - 2));
          result += result1;
        }
      }
    }
    System.out.println(result);
  }
}
```

Comment: What I have done is I have taken that line out completely which was throwing the exception and replaced it with some if statements instead of using the compare to, works perfectly now. Thanks for all your time anyway!